# For faster development of chrome extension can i reload it automatically?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension.

It would be great if, when I save the file, it would reload the extension automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Extension Reloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-reloader/fimgfedafeadlieiabdeeaodndnlbhid?hl=en) extension. It doesn't reload automatically on file save, but you just need to press the button in the toolbar, and refresh the page prior to that if you are injecting code into the page you are on.